# Boost filter in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a book index with fields title, description, author_name, library_id (where the book located). I want to query books that match a provided string, and I also give an array of library_ids for ranking purpose. The results with library_ids that belong to the provided list of library_ids should be ranked higher (higher score).

Is it possible to perform this type of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using ids query

```
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "boost_factor": "50",
               "filter": {
                 "ids": {
                    "values": [
                       "library_ids"
                    ]
                 }
               }
            }
         ],
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "score_mode": "sum"
      }
   }
}
```

library_id must be the "_id" field.